# Convert jquery function to each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following function was created to add an up and down button control to an input field. I need this function to work where there are more than one on the same page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxqty = parseInt($('.qty').attr('max'))

    $(".qtyplus").click(function() {
        if($('.qty').val()<maxqty)
            $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    $(".qtyminus").click(function() {
        if($('.qty').val()>1)
            $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );
    });
});
```

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/BhnM7/

Basically need the function to work it there were several div class="qtybox" on the same page

Comment: What have you tried? `.each()` is probably the right approach but I don't see that in the code you posted.

Comment: Are you trying to increment all the qty boxes with the click of one button? or you want it to work such that each + and - only corresponds to a particular object of class='qty'?

Comment: Why not just use an `<input type="number"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxqty = parseInt($('.qty').attr('max'))
    $(".qtyplus").click(function() {
        if($(this).parent().prev('.qty').val()<maxqty)
            $(this).parent().prev(":text[name='qty']").val(
                Number($(this).parent().prev(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    $(".qtyminus").click(function() {
       if($(this).parent().prev('.qty').val()>1)
           $(this).parent().prev(":text[name='qty']").val( 
              Number($(this).parent().prev(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );
    });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BhnM7/2/)**

Comment: This doesn't take into account different max values set per input field.

Comment: @ScottMurphy: that is because all have same max values.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: if you set different max values set for each `input` it just uses the first one for all of the fields.

Comment: @ScottMurphy: i would have used same logic that is used inside if values would have been different. But as they are same, i kept it simple.

Comment: See this fiddle if you need to set max values independently: http://jsfiddle.net/smurphy/v9zMK/5/

Comment: I provided a different solution below that uses a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Try This, If you really are looking for a function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
convert("qtyplus", "qtyminus", "qty");

    function convert(plusClass,minusClass,txtBoxClass){
        var maxqty = parseInt($('.'+txtBoxClass).attr('max'));
        $("."+plusClass).click(function(){
     if($('.'+txtBoxClass).val()<maxqty)
     $(':text[name='+txtBoxClass+']').val(Number($(':text[name='+txtBoxClass+']').val()) + 1 );
    });
    $("."+minusClass).click(function(){
        if($('.'+txtBoxClass).val()>1)
      $(':text[name='+txtBoxClass+']').val( Number($(':text[name='+txtBoxClass+']').val()) - 1 );

    });
    }
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/BhnM7/6/): http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/BhnM7/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `each()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxqty = parseInt($('.qty').attr('max'))

    $(".qtyplus").click(function () {
        $('.qty').each(function () {
            var maxqty = parseInt($(this).attr('max'))
            if ($(this).val() < maxqty) {
                $(this).val(Number($(this).val()) + 1);
            }
        });
    });
    $(".qtyminus").click(function () {
        $('.qty').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() > 1) {
                $(this).val(Number($(this).val()) - 1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BhnM7/7/

Comment: This approach uses the `each()` function to iterate over all the items that match the selector. Since you have the 'qty' class on the input fields it was an easy selector to write. This approach is clean and clear what the point is.

Answer (score 0):

You can using jQuery's `parent()` and `siblings()` functions to find the corresponding `input` field no matter how many `<div>` you add.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".qtyplus").click(function(event){
        //Use the jQuery even object to get the button that was just clicked
        //Navigate the DOM tree using parent and siblings functions to find the corresponding input box
        var inputBox = $(event.currentTarget).parent().siblings('.qty')[0];
        var maxqty = parseInt($(inputBox).attr('max'));
        if($(inputBox).val() < maxqty)
             $(inputBox).val( Number($(inputBox).val()) + 1 );
    });

    $(".qtyminus").click(function(event){
        //Use the jQuery even object to get the button that was just clicked
        //Navigate the DOM tree using parent and siblings functions to find the corresponding input box
        var inputBox = $(event.currentTarget).parent().siblings('.qty')[0];
     if($(inputBox).val() > 1)
       $(inputBox).val( Number($(inputBox).val()) -1 );
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smurphy/v9zMK/4/

Comment: I believe that using $.on(), event delegation and button values, can get the same accomplished in smaller steps.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use event delegation instead of using each(). You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Here is how to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#qtybox').on('click', '.qtybtn', function(e){
        var $group = $(this).parents('.qty-group');
        var $input = $('.qty', $group);
        var maxValue = parseInt($input.attr('max'));
        var buttonValue = parseInt($(this).val());
        var newValue = parseInt($input.val()) + buttonValue;
        if (newValue <= maxValue && newValue >= 0) {
            $input.val(newValue);
         }
    });

});
```

The code above will listen to one click event in the #qtybox class and look for all descendants with the .qtybtn class.

You can see a working copy [here](http://jsfiddle.net/96f7E/6/).